# How to unzip a string in JavaScript that has been compressed using SharpZipLib

Tags: javascript, string, unzip, sharpziplib

I am having trouble decompressing a string in JavaScript.  There is an XML file that is saved to a database.  Before it is saved it is compressed using SharpZipLib in a VB application.

I am currently writing a web application that receives the compressed string through a Web API using JSON.  What I am trying to do is to decompress the string into its original XML format so it can be used on the client side.  I am trying to do this using JavaScript but I have not come across a way to decompress the string.

Below is an example of the code that I am trying to use with ZLib.js.

```
var buf = new ArrayBuffer(graphic.length);
var bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
for (var i = 0; i < graphic.length; i++) {
    bufView[i] = graphic.charCodeAt(i);
}
var inflate = new Zlib.Inflate(compressed);
var plain = inflate.decompress();
```

I receive an error saying 'Error: unsupported compression method'.

I was able to use an example to compress and then decompress a string using ZLib.js successfully so I'm wondering is there a different compression method being used in SharpZipLib.

I have also tried using js-inflate.min.js to inflate the string but this only returns an empty string.

```
// using js-inflate.min.js
var uncompressed2 = JSInflate.inflate(graphic);
```

Is there a way to decompress a compressed string in JavaScript?  Does SharpZipLib use Gzip or some other compression method that is causing the problem?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the compressed stream? Perhaps first they compress it, then they base64 it. Or perhaps they simply create a DeflateStream (so not a real zip, only the compressed data of the zip without the headers) or perhaps they create a full zip (with headers, filenames, ...)... So many possible options...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by looking at the compressed stream?  The data is just compressed.  Base64 isn't used.

Comment: Can you check if the first two characters of the stream are `PK`?

Comment: The first few characters of the stream are 'UEsDBBQAAA'

Comment: Then I'll say it's encoded in some way. A compressed stream should contain non-alphabetical characters.

Comment: It's base64 encoded, a full ZIP file. Try here http://decode.urih.com/, select Base 64 and paste the text. Click decode. You'll get PK, that is the signature of the ZIP files.

Comment: The stream does have some non-alphabetical characters in it.  This is a longer segment of the stream 'UEsDBBQAAAAIAIBEejn1IJU7mQkAABu3AAALAAAAR3JhcGhpYy54bWzlnVtPG0kWx99X2u+A/J647hcEvGRGq0iZrLSZkeZtZEwneAcb1heZ/fbrgMHHcdfZ6Yqr/k14icDVVbh/Ofc6XX32sVn/NFqOPjXLi7//7e'

Comment: it's clearly base64 encoded. First de-base64 and then inflate.

Comment: If you paste `UEsDBBQAAAAIAIBEejn1IJU7mQkAABu3AAALAAAAR3JhcGhpYy54bWzlnVt` in the site I linked you, you'll even see the name of the contained file: `Graphic.xml`

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I was told that the stream wasn't encoded when it was compressed.  I'll give that a try and see how it goes.

Comment: I've tried a couple of different ways to decode the string using window.atob(graphic) and also using the base64_decode function from https://github.com/kvz/phpjs/blob/master/functions/url/base64_decode.js.  The resulting string looks very short (the value is 'PK') but the length is over 2000 characters.  I have tried decoding the value in an online resource (decodebase64.com) and the value comes out as 'PKDz9õ ; ·Graphic.xmlå[OIÇßWÚïü¸' and so on.  When I try to inflate this string I still get the 'Error: unsupported compression method' message.  Am I using the wrong decoder?

Comment: The problem is that it's a full zip, not simply a stream. You could try `Zlib.Unzip`

Comment: If it doesn't work try first to save the still-encoded base64, then with a command line base64 decoder decode it to a zip file and then open the zip file, so at least you can check if the zip file is ok.

Comment: I tried using Zlib.Unzip and that worked.  I had tried using it before but not with the string decoded and it was returning an error.  Thanks again for all the help.